# Using YAML params: in HTML template

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to automate some document production using rmarkdown and knitr in RStudio.  My rmarkdown document has a YAML header and it includes a 'params:' object which I use in the document to parameterise my analysis.  So the YAML section looks something like this:

```
---
title: 'My Doc Title'
project: 'My project name'
subject: 'Some subject description'

params:
    inputFile: 'notYetDefined'
    inputYear: '00'

---
```

I am calling the .rmd file that this YAML code is in using another r script file with:

```
rmarkdown::render('myRMarkdown.rmd', params = list(inputFile = 'inputs1.txt'))
```

This enables me to pass the values of the params to the .rmd for use in the files.
This works great in the r chunks (eg params$inputFile) however when I try to use these params in the HTML template the values of the params passed in the call to rmarkdown::render() are ignored and instead the default ones are used.

So if the HTML template looks like:

```
<div id="coverTitles">
    $if(project)$
        <p id="coverTitle">$title$</p>
        $if(subject)$
            <p id="coverSubtitle">$params.inputFile$</p>
        $endif$
    $endif$
</div>
```

I get the output:

> **My Doc Title**
>
> notYetDefined

When I was actually trying to get:

> **My Doc Title**
>
> inputs1.txt

The 'inputs1.txt' would hopefully come from the rmarkdown::render() call and be passed on to the HTML template as it is knitr'd.

Can anyone help me to get the 'inputs1.txt' parameter correctly passed on the template for rendering?